# Is Filter Contains all words working well?

Tags: 7, views

I have a View and a filter, with "Contains all words". I see that the SQL contains the expression

```
'%word1%' AND '%word2%',
```

but this is making that if I write "angular", just when I start writing the "a", also words which have the character a and not necessarily start with a will appear, for example "matter".

Shouldn't the placeholder % be only in one place, this way:

```
LIKE ( 'word1%' AND ' word2%' ) AND (' word1%' OR 'word2%')  ... [other combinations]
```

I am hurrying on the suggestion, but that way, it will look for a beggining of string as one of the two (or more) words, and the other words must have an empty space before them if they are not at the beginning.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your Operator to ***Starts with*** and Apply.

[image]

If you need use a specific filter you can alter your view query with this hook:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) 
{
    if($view->name == 'NAME') {

    //here modify your query

    }

}
```

Comment: But wouldn't it force the string to start with the word? I want also that the words to be in the middle of the string, for example. I have tried and seems to work as I say.

Comment: @Cesar if you want modify your query you can use the hook views_query_alter, see my edit

Comment: Ok, but I didn't want to alter anything if possible. I will give it a look at low level. Thanks, Adrian.

Comment: @Cesar do you solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't solve it. It was not too relevant for the project, but I still think that it would need some development from the Views module mainteiners. The only solution I see is that of the hook you suggest, which I have taken, anyway, to incorporate OR and AND and IN operator mixed in the Views filter, which I could not get via UI. I close the question as answered because it provides the elements necessary, though the solution is not complete.

Comment: @Cesar I always take this way, maybe in the future the Views module make our lives more easy ;-)